# Unable to Make a development environment image for Docker opensource development

Tags: docker, makefile, build, docker-build

I am trying to Make a development environment image for Docker opensource development, but I am facing the following Error.
I have cloned the repository from their git page and running it on centos.

I am working in a company and have set the proxy as environmental variable in the Dockerfile.

This is the error I am getting -

```
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  
Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zfs-native/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zfs-native/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to 8080:80 (0.0.31.144). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug this without more detail. From the messages you're getting it looks like either the proxy setting or the apt sources list is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

While Making a build behind the proxy, make sure you set you add http in your environmental variable.

ENV http_proxy **http://**your.company.com:8080

ENV https_proxy **https://**your.company.com:8080